# Verbum vs. nomen

Tags: semiotics, augustine

From a semiotics perspective, what's the difference between *verbum* ("word") and *nomen* ("noun")?

St. Augustine's [*De Magistro*](http://www.augustinus.it/latino/maestro/index.htm) V.12 grapples with this.

Comment: See [Concerning the teacher (De magistro) and On the immortality of the soul (De immortalitate animae)](https://archive.org/details/concerningteache0000augu/) for the translation of the full text.